# Creating duplicates in a python list

Tags: python, list

I want to repeat numbers in a list but I'm not sure how to start. Here's an example of what I'm looking to do

```
list1=[2,4,5,1,7,8,2,9]

list_I_want=[2,2,4,4,5,5,1,1,7,7,8,8,2,2,9,9]
```

I was thinking probably a for loop to do this but I am not sure where to start

Comment: If you’re “*not sure where to start*” on a task like this, Stack Overflow probably isn’t the place for you at this point. You should be seeking out more fundamental literature on Python fundamentals so that you can at least make a base level attempt at meeting the described requirements before posting in accordance with [ask]. We could spoon feed you the answer, but that doesn’t assist in your learning of the language itself at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy method using nested loops in a list comprehension:

```
>>> list1=[2,4,5,1,7,8,2,9]
>>> [i for i in list1 for _ in range(2)]
[2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 2, 2, 9, 9]
```

This is equivalent to doing nested `for` loops and `append`ing in the inner loop:

```
>>> list_i_want = []
>>> for i in list1:
...     for _ in range(2):
...         list_i_want.append(i)
...
>>> list_i_want
[2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 2, 2, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Ok that worked perfectly. Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in-place (i.e. without creating a separate list), you can insert each number at its position in a loop. However, the list indexes will change as you insert new items so, performing the insertions backwards will ensure that the remaining items to process are at their expected positions:

```
list1=[2,4,5,1,7,8,2,9]

for i in reversed(range(len(list1))):
    list1.insert(i,list1[i])

print(list1)
[2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 2, 2, 9, 9]
```